# Do something when slot does not have child nodes in lit-html

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

I'd like to display a text when no content is on the slot.

```js
class List extends LitElement {
  public render() {
    return slot.length === 0 
      ? html`No content is available`
      : html`<slot></slot>`;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use the slotchange event
- https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/#accessing-slotted-children
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may help :

```
render() {
   return html` <slot id="slot">No content is available</slot> 

`;}

firstUpdated(){
      const slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#slot");
      this.slt = slot.assignedNodes();
      if (this.slt.length===0){
        console.log('No content is available')
      } else {
        console.log('Content available', this.slt)
      }
}
```

You can not slot's assigned nodes unless you render slot element. That's why first you need to render it. After there are a lot way to hide it. Another way is to dedect it at it's parents and pass the nr of slot element as property.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-forge-do-something-when-slot-does-not-have-child-nod?file=index.js)